# scheduling time in AVR

Tags: avr, timer

I have a board that have 3 relay. I have 3 function for Set / Reset / Toggle a relay that get a special relay number and do action on that as below:

```
void SetRelay(byte RelayNo) //index 1
{
    switch (RelayNo) {
        case 0:
        S_R1;
        break;
        case 1:
        S_R2;
        break;
        case 2:
        S_R3;
        break;
    }
}

void ResetRelay(byte RelayNo)//index 2
{
    switch (RelayNo) {
        case 0:
        R_R1;
        break;
        case 1:
        R_R2;
        break;
        case 2:
        R_R3;
        break;
    }
}

void ToggleRelay(byte RelayNo)//index 3
{
    switch (RelayNo) {
        case 0:
        T_R1;
        break;
        case 1:
        T_R2;
        break;
        case 2:
        T_R3;
        break;
    }
}
```

I send a packet to board something like:

[image: Packet Data]

**Relay Index**: Index for activate a special relay.

**Function Name**: A index for witch function must execute for special relay index.

**Schedule Time**: Is is a time in millisecond that a function must be fire for special relay index.

A sample packet:

[image: Sample packet]

That mean the board must active

- Relay index `1` must be fire in function number 3(`ToggleRelay`) in 2000 millisecond
- Relay index `3` must be fire in function number 1(`SetRelay`) in 1000 millisecond
- Relay index `1` must be fire in function number 2(`ResetRelay`) in 2200 millisecond

If just want to fire a relay with **one** function its must work with *system timer*, **BUT** anybody have suggestion for how to do that with more than one function?

Comment: Look into the construction of a "Scheduler".  I think that there are two main varieties: cooperative, and pre-emptive.  You must decide which strategy works best for you, and then find a good example to start from.  Once you have the framework in place, it becomes very straight-forward.

Comment: because the scheduler just want to Set / Reset / Toggle a Relay(nothing more) I think must doing in cooperative way.

Comment: There are two classes of scheduler:
1. cooperative. each 'task' runs to completion when it relinquishes the cpu. the scheduler then initiates the next task on the basis of some priority scheme.
2. pre-emptive multi-tasking/threading. each task runs until something causes it to be pre-empted by another task. the pre-emption could be on the basis of priority, cpu usage, entering an event wait state, etc.

Answer (score -1):

Fairly easy.

Time1 = millis()
  If (time1minus time0 is more than timeelapsed0) process relay0

And repeat that for two other relays.

Time0 is updated whenever a new packet was received.

Comment: My question is how handle this issue woth multiple function index! I say in question that if exist one function for doong action for relay its easy and could handle with your answer

Comment: And other thing is mayby recive new packet when proccess last packet and if update timer0 when recieve new packet it lead to lost last operation